# Dados 3 números, mostrarlos por pantalla en orden creciente. esto en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito que alguien me explique esto ya que no lo entiendo, es parte de un ejercicio de estructura de decision en python

Comment: Hola Alex, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Deberías poner un poco más de contexto, los tres números están en un array?, puedes usar un for?.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que entiendo es que el ejercicio pide lo siguiente:

1. pedirle a usuario que ingrese 3 números
2. Comparar los 3 números y ordenarlos de menor a mayor
3. Mostrar los 3 números ordenados de menor a mayor

Existen diferentes formas de resolver ese ejercicio, a continuación te voy a mostrar 2 opciones que se me ocurren:

1. La primera forma sería pedir al usuario que ingrese los 3 números utilizando un bucle for y un input, y se van guardando en un arreglo. Posteriormente se ordena el arreglo con la función sorted() y se imprime el resultado con un print.

   ```
   #Bucle para que no se termine el programa cuando haya un error en el ingreso de información


   while 1: 
       try: #Manejo de excepciones
           #Arreglo vacío para guardar los números que ingrese el usuario
           numeros = []
           #ciclo for para capturar los números
           for i in range(3):
               #Pedir al usuario ingresar los números
               numero= int(input("ingrese 3 número diferentes: ")) 
               #Guardar cada número en el arreglo
               numeros.append(numero)
           #ordenar los números al salir del bucle 
           ordenados = sorted(numeros) 
           #Imprimir el resultado si todo funciona bien
           print("Los números en orden creciente son: ", ordenados) 
           exit() #Salir del programa
       except ValueError:
           #Enviar alerta cuando el usuario ingrese un valor incorrecto
           print("Debe ingresar un número de tipo entero")
   ```
2. La segunda opción es más larga, pero al ser un ejercicio de estructura de decisión es posible que sea la que necesita, ya que se usa una estructura condicional con if's.

```py
while 1:
    try:
        #Pedimos los número uno a uno
        numero1= int(input("ingrese 3 número diferentes: "))
        numero2= int(input("ingrese 3 número diferentes: "))
        numero3= int(input("ingrese 3 número diferentes: "))

        #Hacemos todas las comparaciones posibles entre los 3 números
        if numero1 > numero2:
            if numero2>numero3:
                print("Los números en orden creciente son: ",numero3, numero2, numero1)
            elif numero1>numero3:
                print("Los números en orden creciente son: ",numero2, numero3, numero1)
            else:
                print("Los números en orden creciente son: ",numero2, numero1, numero3)    
        else:
            if numero1>numero3:
                print("Los números en orden creciente son: ",numero3, numero1, numero2)

            elif numero2>numero3:
                print("Los números en orden creciente son: ",numero1, numero3, numero2)       
            else:
                print("Los números en orden creciente son: ",numero1, numero2, numero3)
        exit()                    
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar un número de tipo entero")
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, pedimos al usuario que ingrese los 3 números:

```
num1 = int(input("Introduce el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo número: "))
num3 = int(input("Introduce el tercer número: "))
```

Luego, creamos una lista con los 3 números ingresados y la ordenamos usando el método `sort`:

```
nums = [num1, num2, num3]
nums.sort()
```

Finalmente, imprimimos los números en orden creciente:

```
print("Los números en orden creciente son:")
for num in nums:
    print(num)
```

Código completo:

```
# Pedir los tres números al usuario
num1 = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input("Ingrese el segundo número: "))
num3 = int(input("Ingrese el tercer número: "))

# Almacenar los números en una lista
numbers = [num1, num2, num3]

# Ordenar la lista de números en orden creciente
numbers.sort()

# Mostrar los números en orden creciente
print("Los números en orden creciente son:")
print(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2])
```

Saludos!